# how can i select these in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine that there are two tables called: Customers, Orders.

In Customers we have rows:

```
id=1 name=Alex key=12
id=2 name=Bob key=13
```

and in the Orders we have:

```
id=1 device=phone status=ordered key=12
id=2 device=phone status=delivered key=12
id=3 device=memory status=ordered key=13
id=4 device=memory status=returned key=13
```

Now I want it to choose the last one for each one of them in the Customers from Orders. Like it should choose Alex's information and the last row that is inserted for him in the Orders table.

How can I make a query for this?

Comment: something like `SELECT * FROM Customers, Orders WHERE Customers.key=Orders.key`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with aggregation and a join:

```
select o.*
from customers c left join
     orders o
     on c.key = o.key left join
     (select o.key, max(id) as maxid
      from orders o
      group by o.key
     ) ok
     on o.id = oo.id;
```

The aggregation gets the latest value.

Note that `key` is a reserved word in MySQL (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)).  That makes it a lousy column name, so you should change it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for the group-wise (key) maximum (id) as explained at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

I prefer (for no good reason) the `LEFT JOIN` variant over the uncorrelated sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can do it

```
select 
c.*,
o.id,
o.device,
o.status
from customer c
join orders o on o.`key` = c.`key`
join (
  select max(id) as id,`key` from orders
  group by `key`
)o1 on o1.id=o.id
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96885/2